# Integration services string length need to be truncated

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis, etl

I'm using integration services (SSIS), at the moment I'm getting the data from an excel source, the string `Description` comes with a length greater than 15 chars: the problem is that I can't find a way to truncate this data in order to save it in the database (the column database is varchar(15) and I can't change it).

I was trying to use a derived column in order to truncate the data with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a derived column transformation and use the SUBSTRING function to get only the first 15 characters of the string. Read about the Substring function in SSIS here [SUBSTRING SSIS Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137541.aspx)

Your expression in the derived column would look something like `SUBSTRING(Description, 0, 15)`

Comment: Oh god, I didn't see that, I was gettin' a headache, thanks for your answer, it worked, but apparently it has to be `SUBSTRING(Description, 1, 15)` starting with 1, not 0. Thanks a lot